# problems with fetching JSON data when input change with redux/react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to fetch data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ for practice purposes. I want to fetch /posts, /comments etc. with typed input.

for example: when I type "posts" in textarea, I get data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

then when I type "comments", i get data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments

It works with static set const ROOT_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

When I press button, I'll get data with static url, but withing changing value not sure how to do it.

**STUCK HERE**

How to modify SearchBar component, to take info value from input and then on form submit, it will fetch data depending on value ?

I hope you understood my problem, and thanks !

**actions.js**

```
export const fetchInfo = () => {
const url = `${ROOT_URL}$posts`;
const request = axios.get(url);
return {
  type: FETCH_INFO,
  payload: request
};
}
export function fetchInfoSuccess(posts) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_INFO_SUCCESS,
    payload: posts
  };
}

export function fetchInfoFailure(error) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_INFO_FAILURE,
    payload: error
  };
}
```

**modified action.js(Which I'd like to work)**
with parameter (info)

```
export const fetchInfo = (info) => {
    const url = `${ROOT_URL}${info}`;
    const request = axios.get(url);
    return {
      type: FETCH_INFO,
      payload: request
    };
    }
    export function fetchInfoSuccess(posts) {
      return {
        type: FETCH_INFO_SUCCESS,
        payload: posts
      };
    }

    export function fetchInfoFailure(error) {
      return {
        type: FETCH_INFO_FAILURE,
        payload: error
      };
    }
```

**SearchBarContainer.js**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetch: () => {
      dispatch(fetchInfo()).then((response) => {
            !response.error ? dispatch(fetchInfoSuccess(response.payload)) : dispatch(fetchInfoFailure(response.payload));
          });
    }
  }
}
```

**SearchBarComponent.js**

```
 export default class SearchBar extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {info: ''};
    }

    onInputChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({info: e.target.value});
    }

       handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
      this.props.fetch();
    }

    render () {
      return (
    <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
    <input onChange={this.onInputChange}/>

          <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
        </div>
          )
    }
    }
```

**STUCK HERE**

How to modify SearchBar component, to take info value from input and then on form submit, it will fetch data depending on value ?

Comment: Change this <input onChange={this.onInputChange}</input> to <input onChange={this.onInputChange} />

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment change input component to

```
<input onChange={this.onInputChange} />
```

Bind current instance `this` with two event actions (handleOnSubmit, onInputChange). 
In handleOnSubmit method, pass info state value

```
handleOnSubmit (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  this.props.fetchInfo(this.state.info);
}
```

This may help you https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: It was a typo, but not the problem solution, I just can't figure it out, how to pass state of info, into function fetch, because I get undefined.

Comment: You can pass this.state.info in fetchInfo `this.props.fetchInfo(this.state.info);`

Comment: Already did this before posted here, problem is, I get undefined value.

Comment: Are you getting this.state.info as undefined(inside handleOnSubmit function)?

Comment: I get error when I press submit button, looking on developer tools, it gets a request, but the adress is https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/undefined, and I get an error message, so it means it cant read value of state.info.

Comment: Bind current instance this for handleOnSubmit and onInputChange  inside constructor method. Use this codepen for reference https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/VmmPgp?editors=0011

Comment: No need to bind this if you use arrow functions. Still thank you for trying to help, appreciate it !

Comment: Could you remove that arrow function and try binding current instance?